# Cannot delete Linux directory - infinite recursion

Tags: linux, redhat, nfs

We have an NFS mount on a RHEL6 VM that supports our version control server - recently, one of the repositories went a bit crazy and this is what I found on the server:

```
ls -latri repo.git/refs/heads/

total 28
5551210 drwxr-xr-x. 2 git git 8192 Jun  1 21:21 .
5551210 drwxr-xr-x. 2 git git 8192 Jun  1 21:21
5551210 drwxr-xr-x. 2 git git 8192 Jun  1 21:21
5551209 drwxr-xr-x. 3 git git 4096 Jun  1 22:09 ..
```

When I run `tree` against the dir, it appears to be infinitely recursive - e.g.:

```
repo.git/refs/heads/
├──
│   ├──
│   │   ├──
│   │   │   ├──
│   │   │   │   ├──
│   │   │   │   │   ├──
│   │   │   │   │   │   ├──
│   │   │   │   │   │   │   ├──
│   │   │   │   │   │   │   │   ├──
│   │   │   │   │   │   │   │   │   ├──
│   │   │   │   │   │   │   │   │   │   ├──
│   │   │   │   │   │   │   │   │   │   │   ├──
│   │   │   │   │   │   │   │   │   │   │   │   ├──
│   │   │   │   │   │   │   │   │   │   │   │   │   ├──
│   │   │   │   │   │   │   │   │   │   │   │   │   │   ├──
│   │   │   │   │   │   │   │   │   │   │   │   │   │   │   ├──
│   │   │   │   │   │   │   │   │   │   │   │   │   │   │   │   ├──
```

I have attempted to delete the repository via its inode ref:

```
[root@node repo.git/refs]# ls -latri
total 16
5551210 drwxr-xr-x. 2 git git 8192 Jun  1 21:21 heads

[root@node repo.git/refs]# find . -inum 5551210 -exec rm -rf {} \;
rm: cannot remove `./refs/heads': Directory not empty
find: `./refs/heads/': No such file or directory
find: `./refs/heads/': No such file or directory
```

I am a bit at a loss what to do here - the inode info on the `ls -latri` command seems to indicate that there are 2 directories in the 'heads' directory that are hardlinks to the heads directory?

Any ideas on how to clean this up would be most welcome - think I have solved the application issue it was causing but the bigger issue with the filesystem needs to get sorted.

Thank you!

Edit: bit of additional output:

no hidden characters:

```
[root@node repo.git/refs]# ls -latrib heads/
total 28
5551210 drwxr-xr-x. 2 git git 8192 Jun  1 21:21 .
5551210 drwxr-xr-x. 2 git git 8192 Jun  1 21:21
5551210 drwxr-xr-x. 2 git git 8192 Jun  1 21:21
5551209 drwxr-xr-x. 3 git git 4096 Jun  1 22:09 ..
```

but here is some fun output when I'm actually **in** the heads dir:

```
[root@node repo.git/refs/heads]# ls -latrib
ls: cannot access : No such file or directory
ls: cannot access : No such file or directory
total 12
      ? -?????????? ? ?   ?      ?            ?
      ? -?????????? ? ?   ?      ?            ?
5551210 drwxr-xr-x. 2 git git 8192 Jun  1 21:21 .
5551209 drwxr-xr-x. 3 git git 4096 Jun  1 22:09 ..
```

Comment: Your `ls -latri` output is odd as the link count for inode 5551210 is odd if there are those two extra directories. Could you try `ls -latrib`? What's the underlying filesystem type?

Comment: Hey, file system type is nfs4 - the output with the -b flag is the exact same as without - have added what info I could above

Comment: Have you looked at the problematic directory on the NFS server (the server that your version control VM is mounting the filesystem from)? I think you need to see what it thinks is happening (and it was the filesystem type on the NFS server that I was asking about).

Comment: Unfortunately no access to it - corporate environment and such - will raise a request to get someone in there to have a look on their side.  If I can get more info I will post it up, cheers!

Comment: Is the file system intact? Those question marks in the `ls` output are suspect to me. Have you run fsck on the NFS server?

Comment: We want to but is not that simple - the fileserver is serving our git setup for a large enterprise - we have to schedule some downtime to unmount it and verify the fs.  Will update if we ever make it happen :(

Comment: Have you tried mounting it on a second location as read-only?

Comment: I strongly recommend to do a **fsck**... in particular, before you see any further corruption.

Comment: @oldNoakes: After you've scheduled a downtime schedule the setup of a backup server. What would you do if it broke down *now*?

Comment: still haven't gotten to the bottom of this (no one wants to allow the downtime on the system) but we have a regular backup of the relevant application data on the drive that continues to be successful (and is tested into a staging instance nightly). If I ever find out what is going on, I will be sure to update, just no idea when...

Answer (score 3):

First: Git can neither be the cause nor the solution of a problem that manifests as nonsensical output from `ls`. Stop using Git or other tools on the filesystem and unmount it to avoid harm.

This looks like either a broken filesystem or a broken mount. Try unmounting and remounting the filesystem on the client. Try fully rebooting the client. Try doing the same mount on another client. Each time, check that `ls` output to see if it becomes normal. This will help you diagnose whether the problem is on the NFS server side. If the `ls` output continues to look the same, investigation and repair of the filesystem (`fsck` or whatever) and/or the NFS service (restarting NFS-related daemoons; reboot if nfsd is in-kernel) needs to take place on the server side.